# Python Run Unittest as Package Import Error

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, python-unittest, pythonpath

I. Preface: The application directory structure and modules are listed at the end of the post.

II. Statement of the Problem: If the PYTHONPATH is not set the application runs, but the unittest fails with the **ImportError: No module named models.transactions**. This happens when trying to import 
Transactions in app.py. If the PYTHONPATH is set to `/sandbox/app` both the application and
unittest run with no errors. The constraints for a solution are that the PYTHONPATH should not have to be set, and 
the sys.path should not have to be modified programmatically.

III. Details: Consider the case when the PYTHONPATH is set and the `test_app.py` is run as a package `/sandbox$ python -m unittest tests.test_app`. Looking at the print statements for `__main__`
sprinkled throughout the code:

```
 models   :  app.models.transactions
 models   :  models.transactions
 resources:  app.resources.transactions
 app      :  app.app
 test     :  tests.test_app
```

The unittest imports the app first, and so there is `app.models.transactions`. The next import that the app
attempts is `resources.transactions`. When it is imported it makes its own import of `models.transactions`, and 
then we see the `__name__` for `app.resources.transactions`. This is followed by the `app.app` 
import, and then finally the unittest module `tests.test.app`. Setting the PYTHONPATH allows the application to resolve models.transactions!

One solution is to put the `models.transactions` inside `resources.transaction`. But is there another way to handle the problem?

For completeness, when the application is run the print statements for `__main__` are:

```
 models   :  models.transactions
 resources:  resources.transactions
 app      :  __main__
```

This is expected, and no imports are being attempted which are above `/sandbox/app` or sideways.

IV. Appendix

A.1 Directory Structure:

```
|-- sandbox
    |-- app
        |-- models
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- transactions.py 
        |-- resources
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- transactions.py        
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- app.py
    |-- tests
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- test_app.py
```

A.2 Modules:

(1) app:

```
from flask import Flask
from models.transactions import TransactionsModel
from resources.transactions import Transactions
print '     app      : ', __name__
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
app = create_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

(2) models.transactions

```
print '     model    : ', __name__
class TransactionsModel:
    pass
```

(3) resources.transactions:

```
from models.transactions import TransactionsModel
print '     resources: ', __name__ 
class Transactions:
    pass
```

(4) tests.test_app

```
import unittest 
from app.app import create_app
from app.resources.transactions import Transactions   
print '     test     : ', __name__ 
class DonationTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
    def test_transactions_get_with_none_ids(self):
        self.assertEqual(0, 0) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is worthwhile mentioning up front that the Flask documents say to run the application as a package, and set the environment variable: `FLASK_APP`. The application then runs from the project root: `$ python -m flask run`. Now  the imports will include the application root, such as `app.models.transactions`. Since the unittest is being run in the same way, as a package from the project root, all imports are resolved there as well.

The crux of the problem can be described in the following way. The test_app.py needs access to sideways imports, but if it runs as a script like:

```
/sandbox/test$ python test_app.py
```

it has `__name__==__main__`. This means that imports, such as `from models.transactions import TransactionsModel`, will not be resolved because they are sideways and not lower in the hierarchy. To work around this the test_app.py can be run as a package:

```
/sandbox$ python unittest -m test.test_app
```

The `-m` switch is what tells Python to do this. Now the package has access to `app.model` because it is running in `/sandbox`. The imports in `test_app.py` must reflect this change and become something like:

```
from app.models.transactions import TransactionsModel
```

To make the test run, the imports in the application must now be relative. For example, in app.resources:

```
from ..models.transactions import TransactionsModel
```

So the tests run successfully, but if the application is run it fails! This is the crux to the problem. When the application is run as a script from `/sandbox/app$ python app.py` it hits this relative import `..models.transactions` and returns an error that the program is trying to import above the top level. Fix one, and break the other.

How can one work around this without having to set the PYTHONPATH? A possible solution is to use a conditional in the package `__init__.py` to do conditional imports. An example of what this looks like for the `resources` package is:

```
if __name__ == 'resources':
    from models.transactions import TransactionsModel
    from controllers.transactions import get_transactions
elif __name__ == 'app.resources':
    from ..models.transactions import TransactionsModel
    from ..controllers.transactions import get_transactions
```

The last obstacle to overcome is how do we get this pulled into the `resources.py`. The imports done in the `__init__.py` are bound to that file and are not available to `resources.py`. Normally one would include the following import in `resources.py`:

```
import resources
```

But, again, is it `resources` or `app.resources`? It would seem like the difficulty has just moved further down the road for us. The tools offered by `importlib` can help here, for example the following will make the correct import:

```
from importlib import import_module
import_module(__name__)
```

There are other methods that can be used. For example,

```
TransactionsModel = getattr(import_module(__name__), 'TransactionsModel')
```

This fixed the error in the present context.

Another, more direct solution is using absolute imports in the modules themselves. For example, in resources:

```
models_root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'models')
fp, file_path, desc = imp.find_module(module_name, [models_root])
TransactionsModel = imp.load_module(module_name, fp, file_path, 
    desc).TransactionsModel
TransactionType = imp.load_module(module_name, fp, file_path, 
    desc).TransactionType
```

Just a note concerning changing the PYTHONPATH with `sys.path.append(app_root)`
in `resources.py`. This works well and is a few lines of code located where it needs to be. Additionally, it only changes the path for the executing file and reverts back when finished. Seems like a good use case for unittest. One concern might be when the application is moved to different environments.

Comment: The fact that "it works" should be weighted against the fact that this code is not very "readable:" in other words, other people, those tasked with maintaining the code would have real trouble understanding all that you do here (v. simply providing "wrapper" shell scripts that do "the right thing").  Also, as you add more tests/modules, I have the impression this would become quickly rather unwieldy.

Comment: Absolutely! Not the way to handle imports, unless there are constraints where one is not allowed to change the Python path, sys.path, etc. In the end, as I mentioned in the 1st paragraph above, the way to handle this is to set FLASK_APP, and run both the app & unittest as packages.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: if you can, you should change the two imports:

```
from models.transactions import TransactionsModel
from resources.transactions import Transactions
```

to

```
from app.models.transactions import TransactionsModel
from app.resources.transactions import Transactions
```

Longer version

When you say:

> If the PYTHONPATH is not set the application runs...

how do you run the app?
I am guessing something like...

```
cd sandbox/app
python app.py
```

because either the imports in  `app.py` are incorrect (missing the top-most `app` module) or else running the `app` should equally fail.

IMO you also don't need (stricly) to make `tests` a module (i.e., you can drop `tests/__init__.py`) and just run the tests as:

```
python tests/test_app.py
```

The whole point is that `.` (your current directory) is always by default included in `PYTHONPATH` and it is from there that modules are loaded/searched for imports - in which case, when your tests executes `from app.app import create_app` the first line in `app.py`:

```
from models.transactions import TransactionsModel
```

will cause the error (there is no `./models` module/directory).

If you can't change the imports in the `app.py` application module, or are otherwise constrained, the only option I can think of (other than modifying `PYTHONPATH` or manipulating `sys.path`, which you explicitly excluded), the only other option would be to:

```
cd sandbox/app
python ../tests/test_app.py
```

but then you'd have to change, in your unit tests, your imports:

```
from app import create_app
from resources.transactions import Transactions
```

In other words, you can't have your cake and eat it :)
without changing the Python lookup path, you need to have all modules to start from the same place (`.`) and thus be consistent.

Comment: The application is run as a script, not a package, and this is done in /sandbox/app as python app.py. Using imports like app.models.transactions will not be resolved. I have tried that. The second point is the test_app is run as a package from /sandbox like python -m unittest test.test_app. This allows the tests to access sideways imports and is a common way of running these tests. This works except for the chained imports.

Comment: "Running as a script" v. "running as a package" (assuming the latter even makes sense) is a distinction without a difference :)
What happens if you change your imports in your tests as indicated, then execute your tests from `/sandbox/app` with `python ../tests/test_app.py`
Would this work?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that, within the constraints you have around messing around with the path system, modules/packages must be resolved from `.`: this is where Python will try to resolve imports from (in addition to, obviously, the environment's lib folders and whatever else is already on `$PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`)

Comment: No that does not work. Python -m switch runs a module as a package instead of a script. The script has access to `__main__` and the package has access to `__package__`. This was added to help in cases like this. Try running the code :)

Comment: See the answer I posted for at least 2 solutions to this issue. It turns out you can have your cake and eat it too. Would like to know if there are other more appropriate methods.